# Javascript add new key-value to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON like that :

```
[   {
        "RowID": "1",
        "Name": "Jack",
        "Age": "32",
        "Profesion": "ddddd",
        "Adress": "mmmmmm"
    },
    {
        "RowID": "2",
        "Name": "Joe",
        "Age": "17",
        "Profesion": "oooooo",
        "Adress": "xxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Joe",
        "Age": "17",
        "Profesion": "oooooo",
        "Adress": "xxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    {
        "Name": "mike",
        "Age": "25",
        "Profesion": "ssssss",
        "Adress": "tttttt"
    }
]
```

How can I add in Javascript the key/value `"RowID": "New`" before each key/value `"Name":"..."` in this JSON and how can I loop trough all the key/values that have only `"RowID": "New"` ?

Comment: Can you show your code so far? What didn't work, how did you try to solve it? Can you post a demo to reproduce the problem?

Comment: "Before" does not make sense in JSON objects, as they are unordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
var arr = [   {
        "RowID": "1",
        "Name": "Jack",
        "Age": "32",
        "Profesion": "ddddd",
        "Adress": "mmmmmm"
    },
        {
            "RowID": "2",
            "Name": "Joe",
            "Age": "17",
            "Profesion": "oooooo",
            "Adress": "xxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Joe",
            "Age": "17",
            "Profesion": "oooooo",
            "Adress": "xxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "Name": "mike",
            "Age": "25",
            "Profesion": "ssssss",
            "Adress": "tttttt"
        }
    ];

    arr = arr.map(function(obj){
       if(obj.hasOwnProperty('RowID')){
          obj.RowID = "Old";
       }
       else{
          obj.RowID = "New";
       }
        return obj;
    });
    console.log(arr);

    var newObjs = arr.filter(function(obj){ return obj.RowID === "New" });
    console.log(newObjs);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Give a RowID to each element that doesn't already have one.
list.forEach(item => {
  if (item.RowID === undefined) {
    item.RowID = 'New';
  }
});

// filter out new elements and loop through them
for (const item of list.filter(item => item.RowID === 'New')) {
  console.log(item);
}
```